# How to programmatically/ automatically run OSGi applications

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

When creating Java OSGi projects in eclipse, you run them by .bndrun-> Run OSGi *(for example)*

This does not seem to be really workable when you want to distribute your application to a client, since it would be an inconvenience for them to go about having to manually run the bundles in an OSGi container.

Is there a way I could have a "main" jar\ bundle with a `public static void main(String[] args) {}` class that automatically starts an OSGi container and loads the bundles, as if it was all in one jar file, when a user runs this file?

Answer (score 2):

See the [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org/) site. The [Quick Start](http://enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html) tutorial and the [Base](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/050-start.html) tutorial explain how to export to an executable JAR. If you use Maven, see the [Eval](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_eval/050-start.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the export button in bndtools. It creates a runnable jar that you can distribute.

Bndtools also supports an [automated build using gradle](http://bndtools.org/development.html#building-from-the-command-line).

Recently bndtools also has maven support see [this example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-chat).